# Revert to default variable value?

Tags: ios, swift

Say you have a variable:

```
var x = 6
```

Then you change this later on to, say, 7. Is it possible to revert it back to the original value it was set to (without manually typing x = 6)?

Comment: No, you need to remember somewhere the value and then reassign it.

Comment: not possible.. surely you need a buffer for this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments say, it is not possible, but you can create a simple struct to do this:

```
struct Revertable<T> {
    private let defaultValue: T
    var value: T

    init(defaultValue: T) {
        self.defaultValue = defaultValue
        self.value = defaultValue
    }

    mutating func revert() {
        value = defaultValue
    }
}
```

usage:

```
var a = Revertable(defaultValue: 3)

a.value = 5
a.value

a.revert()
a.value
```